# Inject CDI bean into ContainerRequestFilter results into UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to delegate the work of a request filter to a CDI bean. But Glassfish 4.0 gives me an exceptioon when I call the RestURL.

The filter definition

```
@Provider
@Authenticated
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

@Inject
private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    String token = containerRequestContext.getHeaderString("x-authentication-token");

    if (!authenticationService.isAuthenticated(token)) {

        containerRequestContext.abortWith(Response.serverError().entity("No authentication").build());
    }

}
}
```

Defintion of the NameBinding so that we can tag specific resource URL's.

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Authenticated {
}
```

And the CDI bean definition.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AuthenticationService {
    public boolean isAuthenticated(String token) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (token != null && token.length() > 0) {
            ....
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I do have a bean.xml file in the WEB-INF directory

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

Thanks
Rudy

Comment: What's the exception you are getting?